# Normalising a massive propagator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator

If you take a propagator Greens function for a massless photon from the origin as

$$G(0,x) =  \frac{1}{x^2-t^2 +i \varepsilon}$$

then the normalisation factor at time t is:

$$ N = \int |G(0,x)|^2 d^3x = \int \frac{1}{(x^2-t^2)^2 + \varepsilon^2} d^3 x\approx \frac{|t|}{\varepsilon} $$

(i.e. the probability for a particle being anywhere at time t should be 1).
So dividing by the normalisation factor the propagator is 0 outside the light cone in the limit $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. So the probability density is:

$$ P(x,t) \propto \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{ \varepsilon } { ((x^2-t^2)^2 + \varepsilon^2) |t|} .$$

I am trying to find the same reasoning for the massive propagator, e.g. an electron to show an electron can't travel faster than light, but I am getting wrong results that an electron always will be on the light cone. Any idea how to prove it?

**Edit:** Actually, in fact if an electron was known to start at a single point then the momentum would be completely unknown and hence it could be any momentum from 0 to infinity. Thus the electron would with probability 100% be going at the speed of light and stay on the light cone. Is that correct?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are implying. Both Klein-Gordon and Dirac propagators have different forms.

Comment: I'm sure the proof for one would be applicable to the other.

Comment: different from what you wrote, I mean.